# Find $\psi\in C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ such that $\psi^3+e^x\cdot\psi=id$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, fixed-point-theorems

Show that there exists a unique $\psi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\psi^3+e^x\psi=id$ holds. Furthermore, show that $\psi\in C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ and compute $\psi'(0)$.

---

I'm trying to apply the Banach fixed-point theorem to $C^1$ as a subspace of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, with a suitable metric, which would give us the first part of the exercise. However, I don't know what metric to choose so that the vector space of real functions is complete with respect to this norm and $C^1$ is closed as well (which we need in order to be able to apply the fixed point theorem).
For the second part: I have tried to compute $\psi'(0)$ using the identity $\psi^3+e^x\psi=id$ but the $\psi^3$ seems to be really problematic here.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but the presence of the factor $e^x$ with explicit dependent variable, though it is absent in all other terms, is disconcertingly inconsistent. Does this mean you want to find $\psi$ such that $\psi(x)^3 + e^x\psi(x) = x$ for all $x\in\mathbb  R$? Maybe the notation $\psi^3+\psi\exp = \operatorname{id}$ seems better (at least to me).

Comment: @MPW I agree with you.

Comment: I think writing $\exp \psi$ suggests $\exp(\psi)$ rather than $\exp\cdot\psi$.  Perhaps it looks better to add $\cdot$ in the middle, or write $\psi\exp$.

Comment: I have changed it back since $\exp \psi$ and $\exp \cdot \psi$ might both be understood as the composition.

Comment: Regarding your second question, substituting $x=0$ gives $(\psi ^2 (0) + 1)\psi (0) = 0$. This means that $\psi(0)=0$, since $\psi$ is real valued. Now if you differentiate the functional equation, and substitute $x=0$ you obtain $3\psi '(0)\psi ^2 (0) + \psi (0) + \psi '(0) = 1$ which simplifies to $\psi '(0) = 1$ since $\psi(0)=0$.

Comment: In solving the first part, it might help that for each real $x$, the discriminant of the cubic equation is $ - (4e^{3x}  + 27x^2 ) < 0$, i.e., the equation has only one real solution for each fixed $x$. One has to show that combining all these solutions yields a $C^1$ function. (You can actually give a formula for the real solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(x, \psi)=\psi^3+e^x\psi-x$. We can calculate that $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \psi}=3\psi^2+e^x>0$$ for each $(x, \psi)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. By implicit function theorem, the $\psi$ defined by $F(x,\psi)=0$ exists uniquely in $\mathbb{R}$ and its derivative $$\psi'=-\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial \psi}}=-\frac{e^x\psi-1}{3\psi^2+e^x}$$ also exists everywhere. With $F(0, \psi(0))=\psi(0)^3+\psi(0)=0$ we get $\psi(0)=0$, and the problem is solved.